# How to make various locales available in Google Cloud Functions environment?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I'm running under Python 3.10 in Google Cloud Functions environment. The following code

```
for l in locale.locale_alias:
    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, l)
        print(l + " pass")
    except Exception as e:
        print(l + " fail " + str(e))
```

produces a lot of results, all of them ending with 'fail unsupported locale setting'. How can I make them work?

Comment: I started having this issue when I wanted to update my function to Python 3.12. On 3.7 I could use setlocale() to set it to something different then en_US, but not anymore.